# Closed-form solution for $\int_m^\infty x^{-a} \exp(-b x) \exp(-c x^2) dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Apologies if this is a duplicate. After quite a while searching I couldn't quite find this integral solved in here.

I'm currently working on an application in Probability/Statistics where I need to compute 
$$
\int_m^\infty x^{-a} \exp(-b x) \exp(-c x^2) dx,
$$
where $m >0$, $a>1$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c >0$.
I'd love to not have to compute this by quadrature, although I'd be happy with a principled approximation (i.e., one for which we could control the error $\epsilon$). So let me first ask for a closed-form solution and we'll see if that's possible.

I threw the usual arsenal at it: integration by parts, differentiation under the integral sign, etc. Not claiming these don't work; just that when I tried them it was not fruitful.

### Edits

Following the answer by @martycohen, we can complete the square and, with the change of variables $u = x + \frac{b}{2c}$, arrive at$^\ast$
$$
\int_{m + \frac{b}{2c}}^\infty \left(2cu - b\right)^{-a}\exp(-cu^2)du.
$$
Am not sure how to get out of this quagmire, though.

$^\ast$ ignoring constants.

Comment: Mathematica has no answer for it when $a, b, c, m$ are primer numbers satisfying your conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for
completing the square!

$\begin{array}\\
I(a, b, c)
&=\int_m^\infty x^{-a} \exp(-b x) \exp(-c x^2) dx\\
&=\int_m^\infty x^{-a} \exp(-(cx^2+b x)) dx\\
&=\int_m^\infty x^{-a} \exp(-c(x^2+(b/c) x)) dx\\
&=\int_m^\infty x^{-a} \exp(-c(x^2+(b/c) x+(b^2/(4c^2))-(b^2/(4c^2)))dx\\
&=\int_m^\infty x^{-a} \exp(-c(x+(b/(2c)))^2+c(b^2/(4c^2))) dx\\
&=\exp(c(b^2/(4c^2)))\int_m^\infty x^{-a} \exp(-c(x+(b/(2c)))^2) dx\\
&=\exp(b^2/(4c))\int_{m+b/(2c)}^\infty (y-b/(2c))^{-a} \exp(-cy^2) dy
\quad\text{(error here fixed)}\\
\end{array}
$

This can be integrated
for some values of $a$,
such as the negative of
an odd integer.

If $a$ is the negative of an even integer,
the result involves the
error function.

Comment: I have the feeling that you changed variable in the exponential part but not in the $x^{-a}$ portion. Otherwise $\int x^{-a} \exp(-cx^2)\, dx$ does not make any problem using the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: I have the feeling you are right. I'll fix it later. Thanks.

Comment: @martycohen, am I correct in believing that the variable change you used is $u = x + b/2c$? If so, the $x^{-\alpha}$ term would become $( (2cu-b)/2c)^{-\alpha}$ and the result, albeit ugly, is still "closed-form" [ I'm a statistician; we the error function closed-form].

Comment: You are right. Another careless error of mine.

Comment: I think I was a bit too quick to judge that the resulting integral is solvable. Can we find a closed-form for $\int_l^\infty (2cu-b)^{-a} \exp(-cu^2)du$?

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the antiderivative$$I=\int\left(2cu - b\right)^{-a}\exp(-cu^2)du$$ let use first change variable
$u=\frac t{2c}$ to make 
$$2cI=J=\int (t-b)^{-a} \exp(-k t^2) \qquad \text{where} \qquad k=\frac 1{4c} >0$$
what you can notice if that, if $b=0$, the solution is given by 
$$J=-\frac{1}{2} k^{\frac{a-1}{2}} \Gamma \left(\frac{1-a}{2},k t^2\right)$$ which seem to be valid $\forall a$.

Now, *just as an idea*, why not to write
$$(t-b)^{-a}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{-a}{n}\,b^n\, t^{-(a+n)}$$ making
$$J=-\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{-a}{n}\,b^n\,k^{\frac{a+n-1}{2} } \Gamma \left(-\frac{a+n-1}{2} ,k t^2\right)$$

Comment: I knew that setting $b = 0$ lead to closed-form already, but the final part of your answer reveals that a Taylor approximation of the integrand will lead to a sum of terms of the same form as $J$ above. Insightful! Thanks!

Comment: @LuizMaxCarvalho. In fact, I had this in mind from the time the question appeared. I must confess that I don't know how it would work but, as you said, we basicall face the "same" integral for any order of the expansion. By the way, you are welcome ! Cheers

Comment: @LuizMaxCarvalho. Let $t=b y$ to make things simpler and redefine $k$